# Code Coverage Drop

Tags: code-coverage, apex

My production org had code coverage of 85% but suddenly dropped to 55%. We have written test for every class and we are up to 63%. Anyone else have an idea of why this dramatic drop occurred and why it has become so hard to raise the coverage back up?

Comment: Are you saying all tests are running succesfully ? My guess is some validation rule / newly required field is making existing tests fail.

Comment: I experienced similar things before, but I don't have an answer. Are you cleaning test results? Do you have many non/covered classes?

Comment: Clear your test history and then rerun and its some known issue.Not getting link to official doc but clearing test history should resolve

Comment: Yes all test are passing in the test execution. Also yes we have taken all those measures of clearing out the test and compiling all classes. Apparently there has been a change in how the calculate code coverage. If a class has zero coverage it counts every line regardless of its purpose as not covered. So we have worked to get every class we have covered to at least 75% covered. Still not sure why we can not get it up over 63%. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

You can see what code is covered, and by what tests in the developer console.

If you go to *Your name* > Developer Console, to launch it, you can then execute all tests (unless you are already confident test results are already up to date.)

[image: Click Run All]

Once you have done this, in the bottom right corner there will be a list of each Apex class in your org, with it's coverage..

[image]

Double clicking a file name will load the file into the viewpane and should colourise it by blue/red for lines covered and not covered. In the top left of this pane is a drop down in which you can select "All tests" or the specific test that touched the file to see how it's covering it.

[image]

Using this you should be able to determine what is not covered, and/or what your tests are actually doing (if they are still passing) and get coverage back up!