# Am I testing everything in my test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test, class

I'm trying to get an idea as to whether there is anything I am perhaps missing from my test class?

Here is my apex class:

```
if(null==new_user) {
    return doErr(
        'new_user cannot be null. Must be a <String => String> map.','K001',result
    );
}
String user_name = new_user.get('user_name');

if(null==user_name || ''==user_name) {
    return doErr('new_user.user_name cannot be null or blank.','K002',result);
}

Contact ctc;
Id acct_id;

for(Contact ct:[
    select 
    Id,
    Name,
    AccountId,
    ParFX_Username__c,
    LastName,FirstName,
    Email,
    Platform__c,
    ParFX_Role__c 
    from Contact 
    where ParFX_Username__c=:user_name 
    limit 1]) { 
        //ParFX_Username__c field has 'unique' set
        ctc=ct;
        acct_id=ct.AccountId;
}
if(null!=ctc && ctc.Platform__c!='ParFX') {
    return doErr('new_user.user_name is unavailable: '+user_name,'K003',result);
}

Id art,crt;
for(RecordType rt:[
    SELECT 
        Id,
        DeveloperName 
    FROM RecordType 
    WHERE SobjectType='Account' AND DeveloperName='External'
]) {
    art=rt.Id;
}

for(RecordType rt:[
    SELECT 
        Id,
        DeveloperName 
    FROM RecordType 
    WHERE SobjectType='Contact' 
    AND DeveloperName='External'
 ]) {
    crt=rt.Id;
}

String acct_name;
if(null==acct_id 
        && null!=new_user.get('account') 
        && ''!=new_user.get('account')) {
    acct_name = new_user.get('account');
    for(Account a:[
        select 
            Id,
            Name 
        from Account 
        where RecordTypeId=:art 
        and Name=:acct_name 
        limit 1
    ]) {
        acct_id=a.Id;
    }
}
// At this stage we know whether the Contact and/or Account already exist.
if(null==acct_id) {
    Integer mx_ukn_an=0;
    for(Account a:[
        SELECT 
             id,
             Name 
        FROM Account 
        WHERE Name LIKE '<unknown %'
    ]) {
        if(a.Name.startsWith('<unknown ') && a.Name.length()>10) { 
            String  an = a.Name.substring(9).trim();
            an = an.removeEnd('>');
            Integer  an_n = 0;
            try { an_n = Integer.valueOf(an); } catch(TypeException e) {}
            if(an_n>mx_ukn_an) mx_ukn_an = an_n;
        }
    }
    mx_ukn_an++;
    Account ua = new Account(
        Name='<unknown'+mx_ukn_an.format()+'>',RecordTypeId=art
    );
    try { insert ua; } 
    catch (System.DmlException e) { 
        return doErr(
             'Error while inserting Account: '+e.getMessage(),'D001',result); 
    }
    acct_id = ua.Id;
}
if(null==acct_id) return doErr('Could not create new Account.','D002',result);

if(null==ctc) {
    String last_name = '<unknown last name>';
    if(null!=new_user.get('surname') 
            && ''!= new_user.get('surname')) {
        last_name = new_user.get('surname');
    }
    ctc = new Contact(
        ParFX_Username__c = user_name,
        RecordTypeId=crt,
        LastName=last_name,
        AccountId=acct_id,
        Platform__c='ParFX'
    );
    if(null!=new_user.get('email')) {
        ctc.Email = new_user.get('email');
    }
    if(null!=new_user.get('first_name')) {
        ctc.FirstName = new_user.get('first_name');
    }
    if(null!=new_user.get('role')) {
        ctc.ParFX_Role__c = new_user.get('role');
    }
    try { insert ctc; } 
    catch (System.DmlException e) {
         return doErr(
             'Error while inserting Contact: '+e.getMessage(),'D003',result);
    }
} else {
    if(null!=new_user.get('surname') 
             && ''!= new_user.get('surname')) {
        ctc.LastName = new_user.get('surname');
    }
    if(null!=new_user.get('email')) {
         ctc.Email = new_user.get('email');
    }
    if(null!=new_user.get('first_name')) {
         ctc.FirstName = new_user.get('first_name');
    }
    if( null!=new_user.get('role')) {
         ctc.ParFX_Role__c = new_user.get('role');
    }
    try { update ctc; } 
    catch (System.DmlException e) {
         return doErr(
             'Error while updating Contact: '+e.getMessage(),'D004',result);
    }      
}
if(null==ctc) return doErr('Could not create new Contact.','D005',result);

Opportunity o4c;
for(Opportunity op:[
    select 
        Id,
        Name,
        Web_Login_Provided_by_ParFX__c 
    from Opportunity 
    where AccountId=:ctc.AccountId 
    and Name='ParFX On-Boarding' 
    order by CreatedDate 
    limit 1
 ]) {
    o4c = op;
}
Id rtid;
If(ctc.ParFX_Role__c=='Founder'){
     rtid=[select id from recordType where name='Member'].id;
}
else if (ctc.ParFX_Role__c=='Member'){
     rtid=[select id from recordType where name='Member'].id;
}
else if (ctc.ParFX_Role__c=='ISV'){
     rtid=[select id from recordType where name='ISV'].id;
}
else if (ctc.ParFX_Role__c=='Prime Bank'){
     rtid=[select id from recordType where name='Prime Bank'].id;
}
else if (ctc.ParFX_Role__c=='Prime Client'){
     rtid=[select id from recordType where name='Prime Client'].id;
}
if(null == o4c) {
    Opportunity uo = new Opportunity(
         RecordTypeID=rtid,
         Name='ParFX On=Boarding',
         AccountId=ctc.AccountId,
         StageName='Prospect',
         PrimaryContact__c=ctc.Id,
         CloseDate=Date.today(),
         Web_Login_Provided_by_ParFX__c=Date.today());
    try { insert uo; o4c = uo; } 
    catch (System.DmlException e) {
        return doErr(
            'Error while inserting Opportunity: '+e.getMessage(),'D006',result);
    }
} else {
    if(null==o4c.Web_Login_Provided_by_ParFX__c) {
        o4c.Web_Login_Provided_by_ParFX__c = Date.today();
        try { update o4c; } 
        catch (System.DmlException e) {
            return doErr(
                'Error while updating Opportunity: '
                + e.getMessage(),'D007',result
            );
        }
    }
}

Map<String,Object> user_res = new Map<String,Object>();
user_res.put('account',new_user.get('account'));
user_res.put('user_name',new_user.get('user_name'));
result.put('user',user_res);
result.put('success',1);
String result_str = JSON.serialize(result);
return result_str;
```

And here is the test class:

```
Account a = new Account(Name='Bank of Database Testing2');
insert a;
Contact ctc = new Contact(
     AccountId=a.Id,
     FirstName='Ted',
     LastName='Tester',
     ParFX_Role__c='Founder');
insert ctc ;
Opportunity op = new Opportunity(
    AccountId=a.Id,
    Name='ParFX On-Boarding',
    StageName='Prospect',
    CloseDate=Date.today(),
    Web_Login_Provided_by_ParFX__c=Date.today());
insert op ;

ParFX_NewUser.doPost((Map<String,String>)JSON.deserialize('{\"user_name\":\"adam.sheik\",\"email\":\"adam.sheik@somewhere.org\",\"first_name\":\"Adam\",\"surname\":\"Sheik\",\"role\":\"Analyst\",\"entity\":\"Entity 1\",\"branch\":\"Tokyo\",\"account\":\"<unknown 1>\"}',Map<String,String>.class),'' );
ParFX_NewUser.doPost((Map<String,String>)JSON.deserialize('{\"user_name\":\"buck.rogers\",\"email\":\"adam.sheik@somewhere.org\",\"first_name\":\"Adam\",\"surname\":\"Sheik\",\"role\":\"Analyst\",\"entity\":\"Entity 1\",\"branch\":\"Tokyo\"}',Map<String,String>.class),'' );
ParFX_NewUser.doPost((Map<String,String>)JSON.deserialize('{\"user_name\":\"adam.sheik\",\"email\":\"adam.sheik@somewhere.org\",\"first_name\":\"Adam\",\"surname\":\"Sheik\",\"role\":\"Analyst\",\"entity\":\"Entity 1\",\"branch\":\"Tokyo\",\"account\":\"Bank of Database Testing\"}',Map<String,String>.class),'' );
ParFX_NewUser.doPost((Map<String,String>)JSON.deserialize('{\"user_name\":\"adam.sheik\",\"email\":\"jeffrey.castro@somewhere.org\",\"first_name\":\"Adam\",\"surname\":\"Sheik\",\"role\":\"Analyst\",\"entity\":\"Entity 1\",\"branch\":\"Tokyo\",\"account\":\"Bank of Database Testing\"}',Map<String,String>.class),'' );
```

}

I'm stumped as to what I could be missing here. I've pretty much modified an existing apex class developed for us and wanting to push these changes into my Prod.

Thanks.

Comment: 1. did you get the code coverage of minimum 75%? 2. Is you test class cover all the lines in your class?

Comment: I'm pretty much a newbie at this and this is one of the test methods I run in the test class (run 6 in total). Overall, I'm hitting 65% of code coverage.

Comment: on seeing the test class you missed assert statements which would validate your unit test

Comment: I was going to add these lines into the test class:    Contact updateContact = [SELECT ParFX_Role__c FROM Contact WHERE FirstName='Ted'];
    System.assertEquals ('Member',updatedContact.ParFX_Role__c);
    
    Opportunity updatedOpportunity = [SELECT RecordTypeID,Web_Login_Provided_by_ParFX__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Name = 'ParFX On-Boarding' LIMIT 1];
    System.assertEquals ('Member',updatedOpportunity.RecordTypeID);
    System.assertEquals (Date.today(),updatedOpportunity.Web_Login_Provided_by_ParFX__c);

Comment: Please edit your original post with your revised code and let us know what your coverage is. I don't understand your reference to 6 test methods. Are those 6 methods all on this class or on other classes? If on others, you've confused the question by mentioning them. Otherwise, I'd expect to see them posted with the above.

Answer (score 4):

Using the developer console you can view the test coverage for each class, and when clicking on the class you can see the exact lines that are covered or not. It's explained nicely in this doc:

http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_dev_console_tests_coverage.htm&language=en_US

If you need help getting additional coverage, post that here as a separate question.

Comment: Yes, if you could follow this and post back then 1) you will see yourself where your gaps are and 2) we can help you more specifically target branches of code. I wrote an answer on another question about using the developer console to get code coverage (with screenshots) here, if that also helps.. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24962/code-coverage-drop/24967#24967

Comment: Do that is an answer? Full of links for louis vuitton

Comment: Sagar, sometimes spam bots attempt to overwrite the content of a question or answer. Usually that goes through a suggested edit review, which for an unknown reason was apparently approved by 2 users (http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/9121) . I've rolled back the content to the original answer.

Comment: @Jeff pls mark the question as answered so others can find it back easier. Tnx.